# EE 1.14.0.1 catalog search pager item(s) always 1

Tags: catalogsearch, enterprise-1.14

For a standard search the collection size is always 1, this is breaking pagination as it always thinks there is 1 item from the search result.

The issue is present on the demo @ http://enterprise-demo.user.magentotrial.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=a

[image: Issue]

I set a XDebug breakpoint in the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager` block and looking into the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection` collection the `_getTotals` property is always "1", thus "1 item(s)" is always shown.

This issue does not exist on 1.9.0.1

I am still doing some digging to see exactly where `_getTotals` is set, but has anybody encountered this before?

Comment: May be it's because of group by statement in the select given for count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is having Category Permissions switched on. Debugging shows that when getSize() is called it has a GROUP BY product_id on it. Which gives back many count results but all as 1.

If you switch off Category Permissions, the problem goes away. The other option is to edit getSize() and add a ->reset on the GROUP option.

We've just upgraded a clients from 1.9EE to 1.14EE and this appeared so we have exactly the same issue - we've raised a report with Magento.

Comment: It also breaks the layered navigation search options, thanks barry.